# Архитектура базы данных для прочитанных тем на форуме

Tags: sql, mysql

```
Добрый вечер! Возник вопрос: как построить структуру таблицы под хранение данных о 
    последнем визите пользователя на форум, в тему.
    Существуют две таблицы:
    forumThemes - id | ... | EditDAte
    EditDAte - здесь указывается время последнего добавленного сообщения в тему
    forumRead - id | theme | lastVisit | UserId
    theme - id темы, которую UserId пользователь последний раз посещал в lastVisit времени
    На стороне скрипта будут сравниваться значения EditDAte темы и lastVisit пользователя, если в тему добавилось что-то новое "EditDAte>lastVisit ", то выводим оповещение пользователю.
    Всё было бы хорошо до той поры, пока таблица forumRead была не сильно заполнена. Подскажите пожалуйста, как наиболее удачней ( с точки зрения производительности) организовать данную функцию?
```

Answer (score 2):

Мне представляется, что структура нормальная.

Возможно, требуется просто оптимизировать запросы, скорее всего, построением нужных индексов.